# Create SQL view with dynamic name and columns within Store Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create an SQL table using a stored procedure with a dynamic name and dynamic columns. After creating the table in the stored procedure I want to create a view with that dynamic table name and dynamic columns within the stored procedure.

```
CREATEPROCEDURE [dbo].[Tmp_CloneOfDataset]
  @Filter NVARCHAR(500),
  @Value NVARCHAR(50)=NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  DECLARE @GetTemName varchar(200)= RTRIM(LTRIM( SUBSTRING(@Filter,CHARINDEX('into',@Filter)+4,CHARINDEX('from',@Filter)-CHARINDEX('into',@Filter)-4)))

  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @GetTemName)    
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @alreadyExist int =1;
    return @alreadyExist

    EXECUTE(@Filter)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE(@Filter)

    // Here i want to create view after creating table
    DECLARE @status varchar(200)='SELECT * from '+ @GetTemName

    Execute(@status)
  END     
END
```

Comment: Actually table is creating successfully with dynamic name and dynamic columns using store procedure but i want also to create with table name and table columns view when table is creating. Table name every time will be dynamic and columns also dynamic.

Comment: To create a view, execute `CREATE VIEW ViewName AS SELECT * FROM TABLE`

Comment: You do NOT want to use select * in a view. It can cause all sorts of interesting things to happen if the underlying table(s) change.